# create a loop with a multiplication of a matrix 10 X 4 inside it

Tags: r, loops

I have the following R code to generate 100 random weights

```
# Creating a matrix to store the weights
all_wts <- matrix(nrow = 100,
 ncol = length(tickers))  ### number of tickers 4                   

# run the for loop 100 times.
for (i in 1:100) {
  wts <- runif(length(tickers))
  wts <- wts/sum(wts)

# Storing weight in the matrix
  all_wts[i,] <- wts }
```

So I should have a matrix of weights  $$ w= \begin{bmatrix}
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4 \
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \
\end{bmatrix}$$

where first row $$ w^* = \begin{bmatrix}w1 & w2 &w3& w4  \end{bmatrix}  $$ is the first set of random weights etc .

Now my second step is to multiply first set of random weights with another matrix called $$R_t $$ where $$R_t = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 &A_3 & A_4 \
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \
A_{1,252} & A_{2,252} & A_{3,252}& A_{4,252} \
\end{bmatrix}$$
the code will be

```
a1 <- all_wts[1,] 

b <- log.return

yts <-  rowSums(a1 * b)
```

Then I repeat this multiplication with the second random weights

```
a2 <- all_wts[2,] 

b <- log.return

yts2 <- rowSums(a2*b)
```

I do this for all 100 random weights. My question is, how can I write one code to implement all multiplications for each random weights then store the results of step 2  in  a new matrix so I can move to the third step which needs the results of step 2.

I managed to do the calculation but with iteration more e.g 100 it will be hard to repeat the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go no loops:

```
ncol = 4
nrow = 100
n = ncol * nrow

all_wts = matrix(
  runif(n), nrow = nrow
)
all_wts = all_wts / rowSums(all_wts)

results = apply(all_wts, MARGIN = 1, \(x) rowSums(x * log.return))
```

This isn't tested as you didn't provide any sample data for `log.return`, but it should work. By default, `apply` will try to simplify the results in to a vector or matrix, but you can add the argument `simplify = FALSE` to get a `list` of results if that's more convenient.

Comment: thank you for your help , but what is x here ?  what does \ do in the last line of the code ? Also I want my all_wts to be all positive and sum to 1

Comment: Sorry, used `rnorm` when I should have used `runif` like you did - that introduced the negative numbers. FIxed now. `\(x)` is a shorthand for `function(x)` creating an anonymous function.

Comment: `apply` runs a function on each row or column of a matrix. `MARGIN = 1` tells it we want to run the function on each row. `\(x) rowSums(x * log.return)` is the function to run, and `x` is the argument name I used. `apply` will pass each row of `all_wts` to `x` and stick the results together.

Comment: (You could change `x` to `y` or `foo` or `my_row` or whatever argument name you'd like.)